# Not getting incident reference number when I run a vbscript

Tags: soap, vbscript, servicenow, wsh

I'm trying to retrieve a incident reference number when I run a vbscript. The script opens the ticket with the script ticket values in the code but it returns the following error: *Error: Necessary object: 'oWSResponseDoc.selectSingleNode(...)'*

The code I am using is

```
' Perform the insert and check the status
If Not wsInsertIncident.Post Then
  WScript.Echo "Error=" & wsInsertIncident.Status 
  WScript.Echo wsInsertIncident.StatusText
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim strIncidentSysId, strIncidentNumber
strIncidentSysId = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("sys_id")
strIncidentNumber = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("number")
WScript.Echo "Inserted: " & strIncidentNumber
```

I know this worked in the past but today it doesn't. I don't know what has changed. Full script can be seen here:

https://servicenowsoap.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/vb-script/

Can you please help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular case you're trying to solve? You may be better off avoiding vbscript.

Comment: The particular case i am trying to solve is really this one, cap kirk! I like a lot vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `SetMethod` function before you can insert an incident. This is used to determine what action to take when you make the web call.

I tested this on a demo instance and it created the incident and returned a number.

```
' Specify the ticket values
Dim wsInsertIncident : Set wsInsertIncident = New ServiceNowDirectWS
wsInsertIncident.SetMethod "incident", "insert"
wsInsertIncident.SetValue "short_description", "Demo WS Incident"
wsInsertIncident.SetValue "description", "Demo WS Incident"
wsInsertIncident.SetValue "caller_id", "Abel Tuter"
wsInsertIncident.SetValue "category", "hardware"
wsInsertIncident.SetValue "subcategory", "mouse"

' Perform the insert and check the status
If Not wsInsertIncident.Post Then
  WScript.Echo "Error=" & wsInsertIncident.Status 
  WScript.Echo wsInsertIncident.StatusText
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim strIncidentSysId, strIncidentNumber
strIncidentSysId = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("sys_id")
strIncidentNumber = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("number")
WScript.Echo "Inserted: " & strIncidentNumber

Dim objShell : Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Popup "Inserted: " & strIncidentNumber,, "ServiceNow ticket!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know the incident is created but did you get a popup window with the number? I'm not getting that on my side. I'm running directly the vbscript. Did you get that by using powershell?

Comment: Yeah, just from powershell. No popup, it's just in the output of the console. If you are running it directly, you'll need a popup. I've added a couple of lines to do a popup if that helps

Comment: Sorry, still the same error, still no popup.
You are trying to include a popup at the same time you already have an echo, is that right?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error unfortunately. I've pasted the full code I've used here. https://pastebin.com/sDSvJJnU Just save it to a `.vbs` file and change the 3 variables at the top, hopefully it helps.

Comment: I've manage to correct the error. I've changed into this:

`' Perform the insert and check the status
If Not wsInsertIncident.Post Then
  WScript.Echo "Error=" & wsInsertIncident.Status 
  WScript.Echo wsInsertIncident.StatusText

Dim strIncidentSysId, strIncidentNumber
strIncidentSysId = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("sys_id")
strIncidentNumber = wsInsertIncident.GetValue("number")
WScript.Echo "Inserted: " & strIncidentNumber

  WScript.Quit
End If`

Comment: Yet, still not getting any popup alert after running the script by double clicking the vbs. Tried in 3 diferent OS's. Sorry. It's ok. Thx